# In Android Studio poor ImageButton quality

Tags: android

Ok I am creating an android app I have it all done the problem is a company wants me to use their logo on the ImageButton in the app. The problem is no matter what quality the image starts at and it doesn't matter if it is a 9 patch or just a png the image looks very pixelated unless it is very tiny which then means you can't see it when you run the app.  I have looked and looked and every thing I have come across so far doesn't help.
[image]

Here is an example I am just using a pic off my computer as an example this ^^^^^ is the orignial.
[image]

Here is after hard to tell with out enlarging the picture it has to do with stretching to fit the background of the app or image button.

Comment: at least show us the image, or the code you are attempting

Comment: your answer to this dilemma is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I added an image just for example hard to see in here but I believe it has something to do with the image having to stretch to fit background of app or image buttons.

Comment: I have gotten this to almost work using Android Asset Studio but even with using this my mdpi and hdpi image is distorted. I am setting the image as the background and in landscape the image looks beautiful but in portrait the image stretches in the middle. What would be causing this?

Comment: I  have since go this to work after using android asset studio to create simple nine patch then loading images into my project I have to open each picture and click on show bad patches then slide the red lines off the image then it displays with better quality.